# My Custom Control won't work when use inside of a Method in C#

Tags: c#, controls

So I've made a custom control in C# (it's a circular progress bar), and I have created some variables in it such as Min, Max and Value (every progress bar must have that) and whenever I use those variables inside of a method (lets say a button click event) the code compiles normally without any syntax errors but doesn't actually do anything. But when I use it inside of my form's main method it works just fine. Here's the code I've just described.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        circlebar1.Value++; 
    }
}
```

[Image of what I'm trying to say](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j8r5h.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You write it in a wrong place. In a program, you can modify stuff only inside *methods*. Methods are named sections of code inside *classes*, e.g.

```
public class X
{
  public void DoSomething() //this is a method
  {
    //write your code here
  }
  //not here!
}
```

read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173114.aspx

p.s. you should apply [Category] attribute to *properties*, not *fields*. And fields should normally be *private*.

```
private int _Value;  //this is a field
[Category("MyCathegory")]  //this attribute is used by the Visual Studio properties window to organize your control's properties
public int Value 
{ 
    get { return _Value; }
    set { _Value = value; }
}
```

Properties are used to *encapsulate* fields. Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x9fsa0sw.aspx

Answer (score 0):

why are you declaring _value in a different way from how you declare the other two properties(min/max value)?

it should probably be:

```
private int _value;

public int Value
{
    get{ return _value;}
    set{ _value = value;}
}
```

then use it like:

```
Circle_Progressbar.Circlebar.Value = 50;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I tried what you said (it did clean the code up a lot) but when I use it inside of a form I still get the error 'Circle_Progressbar.Circlebar.Value' is a 'property' but is used like a 'type''

Comment: @ArjanSingh did you put the line 'Circle_Progressbar.Circlebar.Value = 50;' in a method or directly inside a class?

Comment: I put the code inside of a method which ended up working but that code doesn't actually do anything, for example if I go to the properties and change the value to say 25 it'll work there but if I do the same in code it won't do anything but the compiler now accepts the code without a syntax error.

Comment: @ArjanSingh you should run the program to execute your code. The method which changes the value should be called either from the Main method (if your statement is not already in the Main) or from some event handler.

Comment: Could you give me an example :)

Comment: here's a nice tutorial (event handling from ~7:40)
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ucRe9Esv1K4

Comment: @tsayper if I use the code inside of the Main Method it works fine, but whenever I use say inside of a method (let's assume a timer tick event) my custom progress bar control doesn't do anything, it compiles without an error but it won't increment or use a value I set inside of that method.

Comment: @Arjan Singh as for Timer you should set its Enabled property to true otherwise it wont produce Tick events and so your code wont be called.

Comment: @I definitely did enable the timer, but for that matter the custom control won't work inside of any method. Like a button click event, earlier on you said I need to do something with an eventhandler. I watched a couple of videos on it but don't understand how to implement it properly, could that be it? If it is please help me lol